# What is the proper way to perform color replacement

Tags: color, paint.net

Currently, I have a good image, which I originally obtain from web.

[image]

Since I have 2 different themes for my app. I need a same image, but with different foreground color. I use "bucket fill", to perform color replacement.

[image]

However, such technique doesn't handle anti-alias well. In fact, you will get a zig-zag result, when using this simple technique to perform color replacement. This is what it looks like, when I zoom-in to the "eye" region.

[image]

The "zig-zag" effect is obvious, when the app is deployed to a low DPI android device.

### App's outlook when using original image

[image]

### App's outlook when using color replaced image (Zig-zag effect seen)

[image]

May I know what are some proper ways to perform color replacement?

Comment: IDK abut paint.net  but in PS you would go to blending and color overlay  for a proper color change.

Comment: Rule of thumb, if you find yourself using paintbucket then your doing something wrong. I dont have paint dot net installed but can you select the transparency mask?

Comment: @joojaa Nope. I check the Layers windows, I saw there is only 1 Layer named background. I do have a more advanced image editing tool called GIMP. I try to follow http://superuser.com/a/718521 but the "Color to Alpha" is disabled.

Comment: Am too tired to write this as an answer right now, but get Gray to Alpha and you can remove perfectly white/black backgrounds from grayscale drawings with 100% precision, then go about coloring the foreground as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the bucket tool.  From your original image:

Go to **adjustments** in the top menu and then **curves**

[image]

Having it set to **luminosity** will allow you to control the brightness and contrast by dragging the curve about.

Changing to **RGB** will allow you to control the amount of each colour in the layer.

As you move them you should see your image update and the anti aliasing remain in place.